# Additional space between two view iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have 3 `Uiview(uiview1, uiview2, uiview3)`  that contains a TableView and a label. All these are now embedded inside `UIVIew` and which again inside a scroll view.
`The Frame of UIVIew1 is (0,0,321,140)` and `UIVIew2 is (0 , 126 ,321 , 140)` and `UIVIew3 (0,250,321,140)`.  The table views & label are fitting okay inside the views.

But there is a big gap between `UIVIew1 & UIVIew2 & UIVIew3` when i run in simulator.
linked image :http://gyazo.com/22802f8f5b555bafa872b61307f2a151 
i cannot use auto layout here.
I have tried may possibilities and it's quite frustrating..
pls help

Comment: can i see your piece of code?

Comment: @RajPatil all is done in IB. Nothing is being set in code.

Comment: Going to have to know more about the parameters you have set for each and all views!

Comment: yes.. @trumpetlicks.its for all views..

Comment: not able to see the image! it looks like your views will overlap eachother

Comment: @RijoJoseph see the gap between "Action Required" and "has all visible debris".a big blank space is there.

Answer (score 0):

I would go in and make sure you have 'use auto-layout' shut off on the xib file of the view controller, and make sure you have AutoresizeSubviews set to NO on all of the views and subviews.  Other than that its hard to tell without more information..

Comment: i have disabled auto layout and autoresizeSubviews is also set to No. What other info. could be helpful?

Comment: Are you generating all of the views in code or in xibs? If code, could you post some code?

Comment: all are generated in IB.

Comment: sorry - didn't notice there was an answer! If you still haven't got this, you could post a  screenshot of the xib file before you are running it maybe?